# Local connection with Database

Tags: mysql, database, delphi, connection, local

How do I connect my local client application with the database on the server?

I am using Delphi and MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the RageZ's answer, based on your comments to it:

If you don't have an IP address, machine name, or UNC path name, you don't know where the server IS, so you won't be able to connect to it. You'll need an address of *some* kind. If you can log into the server, you should be able to get its address.

Is it on a web host or something? Are you having to get through firewalls?

Comment: Is a Lan... I have only the name of the computer

Comment: Have you tried connecting to it using the tools it comes with? I'm not MySQL expert (at ALL), so don't know what those would be, but I had to do that once w/MS SQL Server, and it saved the day / helped me figure out what to use in the connection string.

Comment: Have you tried resolving the name to an IP address? Or just putting the name instead of "localhost"? If that doesn't work, what are the error(s) you're getting?

Answer (score -1):

you gonna have to download some component [there](http://www.devart.com/mydac/download.html) and probably the mysql client library

Good luck.

Comment: I know how to connect to the database on my computer but do not know how to connect to other computer on the LAN

Comment: I think this have something to do with setting up the connectionString. what are you using to connect to MySQL so far ?

Comment: on my computer I connect with mysql using "localhost" ... how to connect to mysql on another network without knowing the IP of the same?